Apparent position of object in bowl of water
Say you have a bowl of water and you keep an object in it. What would the apparent position of an object inside the bowl from the position of an outside observer? Will the curvature of the spherical bowl change the position of the object inside. The question I am basing this on is the following: "Mr. A is observing a fish swimming in water inside a spherical bowl of glass. If the fish is 5 cm from the front wall of the 10-cm radius bowl, where does the goldfish appear to Mr. A? (Round to the nearest integer)". The answer is 15 cm. I am not looking for this specific question, but questions like this. The question above was just an example of how you take into account for curvature in Snell's Law.

I don't think this is a homework question. It is asking how you model a system like an object behind a curved surface.

Astrovis: when you are looking at fish you are effectively looking though a planoconvex lens then a plane water surface like this. So you calculate the fish's image by first finding the virtual image created by the flat water surface, then use that as a virtual object for the planoconvex lens to calculate the final image position.

This is a general principle that can be applied to any system. Just split it up into a series of simple elements.
